# Syntax error in Java with else

Tags: java

I have two errors with the "else" and I don't know what to do. They are marked with a Comment!!
"Punto" and "Cuadrante" are imported. There is also an enumeration.

```
 public static Cuadrante obtenerCuadrante (Punto p){

            Cuadrante res = Cuadrante.EJE;

            if (p.getX()>0 && p.getY()>0){
                    res = Cuadrante.PRIMER_CUADRANTE;

            }else{
                if (p.getX()>0 && p.getY()<0){
                    res = Cuadrante.CUARTO_CUADRANTE;

            }else{    //Here appears an error: Syntax error on token "else".!!!!!!!!!!!!
                if (p.getX()<0 && p.getY()>0){
                    res = Cuadrante.SEGUNDO_CUADRANTE;

            }else{   //And here too.!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                if (p.getX()<0 && p.getY()<0){
                    res = Cuadrante.TERCER_CUADRANTE;
            }else{
                    res = Cuadrante.EJE;
            }

            }
        }
    }
    return res;
    }
```

Comment: You have lot of misplaced `{` and `}`'s. Take a time do it one by one you will find out issue.

Comment: The elses are into others if...

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: I don't think the code you posted is the code that's giving you the problem.  I tried it, and it compiles fine.  However, your indentation is **very** non-standard, and it's confusing everybody else who is trying to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use if and else if to achieve what you want

```
if(condition){
  // if condition is true
} else if(condition1) {
  // if condition1 is true & condition is false
} else if(condition2) {
  // if condition2 is true & condition1 , condition is false
} else {
  // if condition2, condition1 & condition is false
}
```

You can have more that one else if.

You code currently is which is missing a few closing braces `}` that result in the error that you have and can be fixed like :

```
public static Cuadrante obtenerCuadrante (Punto p){
    Cuadrante res = Cuadrante.EJE;
    if (p.getX()>0 && p.getY()>0){
        res = Cuadrante.PRIMER_CUADRANTE;
    } else {
        if (p.getX() > 0 && p.getY() < 0) {
            res = Cuadrante.CUARTO_CUADRANTE;
        } else {  
            if (p.getX() < 0 && p.getY() > 0) {
                res = Cuadrante.SEGUNDO_CUADRANTE;
            } else {
                if (p.getX() < 0 && p.getY() < 0) {
                    res = Cuadrante.TERCER_CUADRANTE;
                } else {
                    res = Cuadrante.EJE;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Another/better way of doing this is :

```
public static Cuadrante obtenerCuadrante (Punto p){
    Cuadrante res = Cuadrante.EJE;
    if (p.getX()>0 && p.getY()>0){
            res = Cuadrante.PRIMER_CUADRANTE;
    } else if (p.getX()>0 && p.getY()<0){
            res = Cuadrante.CUARTO_CUADRANTE;
    } else if (p.getX()<0 && p.getY()>0){
            res = Cuadrante.SEGUNDO_CUADRANTE;
    } else if (p.getX()<0 && p.getY()<0){
            res = Cuadrante.TERCER_CUADRANTE;
    } else {
            res = Cuadrante.EJE;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Using `else if` like this is definitely better than the originally posted code.  However, I still can't figure out why the original code got errors.  Everybody is saying "you can only have one else", but if you look carefully, each `else` is attached to a more nested `if` inside curly braces, which is legal; the indentation is very unusual and doesn't reflect the nesting, which makes it hard to read.  I strongly suspect that a curly brace got added or dropped when the code was posted.

Comment: @ajb If you look closely the problem is OP had one if and multiple else like : if(){}else{}else{}else{}else{} doesn't matter what the code inside is. This would result in misplaced else compile error.

Comment: No, it's more like if(){}else{if(){}else{if(){}else{if(){}else{}}}}.  I did look carefully, and I also pasted it into a file and tried compiling it myself.  Each `else` is more nested than the previous one.  (But if the OP edited it after posting originally, I may have missed the original version.)

Answer (score 2):

Probably your code should be like this:

```
 public static Cuadrante obtenerCuadrante (Punto p){

            Cuadrante res = Cuadrante.EJE;

            if (p.getX()>0 && p.getY()>0){
                    res = Cuadrante.PRIMER_CUADRANTE;

            }else if (p.getX()>0 && p.getY()<0){

                    res = Cuadrante.CUARTO_CUADRANTE;

            }else if (p.getX()<0 && p.getY()>0){   

                    res = Cuadrante.SEGUNDO_CUADRANTE;

            }else  if (p.getX()<0 && p.getY()<0){  

                    res = Cuadrante.TERCER_CUADRANTE;
            }else{
                    res = Cuadrante.EJE;
            }
    return res;
    }
```

Comment: Please check if you code complies ... in my opinion it doesn't cause you have an extra }

Comment: @Shirish please read my answer !http://stackoverflow.com/a/26491980/1085186 ajb pointed out that i was incorrect.

Comment: @wrongAnswer : he didnt call it as incorrect though he just figured out what better could have been done..
And i sincerely appreciate you for modifying your answer as he said and reposting it..Cheers..!+1 from my side for that..:-)

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one else.

Instead of this

```
else{
                if (p.getX()>0 && p.getY()<0){
                    res = Cuadrante.CUARTO_CUADRANTE;

            }
```

do this:

```
 else if(p.getX()>0 && p.getY()<0){

                        res = Cuadrante.CUARTO_CUADRANTE;

                }
```

Do the same for all the "else" except the last "else"