# Counting Vowels, Repetition method

Tags: java, bluej

```
    public static void main(String args[])
     {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int countVowel=0;
        int countVowelA=0;
        int countVowelE=0;
        int countVowelI=0;
        int countVowelO=0;
        int countVowelU=0;
        char ch;
        String str;
        System.out.println("Please enter the string : ");
        str = sc.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0; i<=str.length(); i ++)
        {
            ch = str.charAt(i);
            if(ch == 'a' || ch =='A')
            {
                countVowelA++;                 
                countVowel++;
            }
            if(ch == 'e' || ch =='E')
            {
                countVowelE++;
                countVowel++;
            }
            if(ch == 'i' || ch =='I')
            {
                countVowelI++;
                countVowel++;
            }
            if(ch == 'o' || ch =='O')
            {
                countVowelO++;
                countVowel++;
            }
            if(ch == 'u' || ch =='U')
            {
                countVowelU++;
                countVowel++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("Occurances of A in given string  : " +countVowelA);
        System.out.println("Occurances of E in given string  : " +countVowelE);
        System.out.println("Occurances of I in given string  : " +countVowelI);
        System.out.println("Occurances of O in given string  : " +countVowelO);
        System.out.println("Occurances of U in given string  : " +countVowelU);
        System.out.println("Number of vowels in strings are  : " +countVowel);
    }
}
```

For me i am having trouble, let's say for example if i type lebron james is the best basketball player, u know it. It gives me an error and also it doesn't count all the vowels? Also, can u tell if my code is right

Comment: Are you sure about that `i++;` at the end of your for-loop?

Comment: The way to tell if your code is right is to test it on all kinds of inputs, and see that it doesn't give you errors, and gives you the correct answer every time. If it doesn't, then it's not right. But besides that, you need to show us what error you get, including what line it complains about. And it would be helpful if you marked your input example (the Lebron James thing) as something that sets it apart, like bold, code, italic, put it in quotes, etc.

Comment: @Bably it means: use a debugger. Did you do that? There are two bugs in this code, very easy to spot with a debugger.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use string methods to find and count vowels in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734630/use-string-methods-to-find-and-count-vowels-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check line below

```
 for(int i = 0; i<=str.length(); i ++)
```

change to

```
 for(int i = 0; i<str.length(); i ++)
```

why?

Because in `Java`, index start from zero. When you have `i <= str.length`, it goes beyond scope index of string and gives you `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

**Another issue**, You have incremented variable `i` **twice**. Second after if clauses is totally unnecessary because it gives you wrong answer even if you rectify the boundary issue.

Comment: Almost prefect ? it will go in all if's you should ask him to change it to else if ...

Comment: @wrongAnswer thank you for your input. I thought about it, but I think it does not make huge difference :)

Comment: @KickButtowski also using a separate counter for counting all seems redundant. !

Comment: @KickButtowski try running that loop 1000 time as it is and a 1000 times with else if ... you will see the difference. AFAIK check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26491980/1085186 the first part how else if works ...

Comment: @wrongAnswer if it is the case, the better solution is Switch Statement.

Comment: @Bably do you still have issue?

Comment: @KickButtowski you can just do countVowelA+countVowelE+... add all to get total count you don't need another variable !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63520/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-wronganswer).

Answer (score 1):

Your loop variable `i`, as was mentioned in the comments, is incremented twice. Once in the for statement itself, and the other at the end of the loop.

This means that the counter goes: 0,2,4,6 instead of 0,1,2,3.

That will give you the wrong answer.

However, the reason for the error is not this, but the fact that you check the condition until `i <= str.length()`, instead of `i < str.length()`. The characters in a string with, say, 3 characters like "the" are 0,1,2. There is no character number 3. So when i is equal to str.length, you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CountVowels {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int countVowel=0;
        int countVowelA=0;
        int countVowelE=0;
        int countVowelI=0;
        int countVowelO=0;
        int countVowelU=0;
        char ch;
        String str;
        System.out.println("Please enter the string : ");
        str = sc.nextLine();
        char[] c = str.toCharArray();
        for(int i = 0; i<c.length; i ++)
        {
            if(c[i] == 'a' || c[i] =='A')
            {
                countVowelA++;                 
                countVowel++;
            }
            else if(c[i] == 'e' || c[i] =='E')
            {
                countVowelE++;
                countVowel++;
            }
            else if(c[i] == 'i' || c[i] =='I')
            {
                countVowelI++;
                countVowel++;
            }
            else if(c[i] == 'o' || c[i] =='O')
            {
                countVowelO++;
                countVowel++;
            }
            else if(c[i] == 'u' || c[i] =='U')
            {
                countVowelU++;
                countVowel++;
            }
            //i++;
        }
        System.out.println("Occurances of A in given string  : " +countVowelA);
        System.out.println("Occurances of E in given string  : " +countVowelE);
        System.out.println("Occurances of I in given string  : " +countVowelI);
        System.out.println("Occurances of O in given string  : " +countVowelO);
        System.out.println("Occurances of U in given string  : " +countVowelU);
        System.out.println("Number of vowels in strings are  : " +countVowel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dumping bunch of code leads your post to be flagged as low quality answer. please provide some explanation.

Comment: @Bably str.toCharArray(); transform your string to an array  of char so you can loop over it to find any vowels

Comment: @ Kick Buttowski : the question is clear and I try to give Bably  a code that he can execute so I just only make some change to his code

Comment: @ Kick Buttowski : I did not.I got -1 in my post