# Procedure Method, counting vowels

Tags: java

My code works fine however I don't know if my code is in procedure Method.

I know that you are supposed to have two methods, but I am not sure if I did the method right, though. So, can you please help me?

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    vowels();
}

public static void vowels(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int countVowel=0;
    int countVowelA=0;
    int countVowelE=0;
    int countVowelI=0;
    int countVowelO=0;
    int countVowelU=0;
    char ch;
    String str;
    System.out.println("Please enter the string : ");
    str = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println();

    for(int i = 0; i<str.length(); i ++){
        ch = str.charAt(i);
        if(ch == 'a' || ch =='A'){
            countVowelA++;                 
            countVowel++;
        }
        if(ch == 'e' || ch =='E'){
            countVowelE++;
            countVowel++;
        }
        if(ch == 'i' || ch =='I'){
            countVowelI++;
            countVowel++;
        }
        if(ch == 'o' || ch =='O'){
            countVowelO++;
            countVowel++;
        }
        if(ch == 'u' || ch =='U'){
            countVowelU++;
            countVowel++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Occurances of A in given string  : " +countVowelA);
    System.out.println("Occurances of E in given string  : " +countVowelE);
    System.out.println("Occurances of I in given string  : " +countVowelI);
    System.out.println("Occurances of O in given string  : " +countVowelO);
    System.out.println("Occurances of U in given string  : " +countVowelU);
    System.out.println("Number of vowels in strings are  : " +countVowel);
}
```

Comment: By "Procedure" method your teacher probably meant a method for doing the calculations(work).  You should be fine...

Comment: You could get the String in the main method then pass it to your vowels(String userInput) method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is fine just some improvements.

```
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.*;

class CountVowels{
    static int countVowelA=0,countVowelE=0,countVowelI=0,countVowelO=0,countVowelU=0,countConsonants=0;
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str="";
        System.out.println("Please enter the string : ");
        str = sc.nextLine().trim();
        System.out.println();
        countVowels(str);
        printVowelsCount();
    }

    public static void countVowels(String str){
        char ch;
        for(int i = 0; i<str.length(); i ++){
            ch = str.charAt(i);
            if(ch == 'a' || ch =='A') {
                countVowelA++;
            } else if(ch == 'e' || ch =='E') {
                countVowelE++;
            } else if(ch == 'i' || ch =='I') {
                countVowelI++;
            } else if(ch == 'o' || ch =='O') {
                countVowelO++;
            } else if(ch == 'u' || ch =='U') {
                countVowelU++;
            } else if(Character.isLetter(ch)){
                countConsonants++;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printVowelsCount(){
        System.out.println("Occurances of A in given string  : " +countVowelA);
        System.out.println("Occurances of E in given string  : " +countVowelE);
        System.out.println("Occurances of I in given string  : " +countVowelI);
        System.out.println("Occurances of O in given string  : " +countVowelO);
        System.out.println("Occurances of U in given string  : " +countVowelU);
        System.out.println("Number of vowels in strings are  : " +(countVowelA+countVowelE+countVowelI+countVowelO+countVowelU));
        System.out.println("Number of Consonants : " +countConsonants);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's slightly better. Now I have to ask: why do you moved the variables into `static` fields? While it solve the problem, calculating the vowels of a second word will fail.

Comment: That is out of the scope of main you would have to re run the program ! I did it cause i didn't want to return a array of the int or write a another class which would have the count ... and use that !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63965/discussion-between-stackflowed-and-luiggi-mendoza).

Comment: @Bably [check this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter(char)) to understand what isLetter does. its just another check. to understand else if see ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/26491980/1085186 first part !

Comment: @Bably that is not accurate as the input change have hyphens or digits or some other symbols / punctuations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64020/discussion-between-stackflowed-and-bably).

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting another improvement, you can do without any loops, and a very few variables

```
 class SourceBee{
    public static void main(String args[]){
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter the string : ");
            String str = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println();
            printVowelsCount(str);
        }

    public static void printVowelsCount(String vowels) {
        System.out.println(vowels);
        int length = vowels.length();
        System.out.println("a count: " + (length - vowels.replace("a", "").length()));
        System.out.println("e count: " + (length - vowels.replace("e", "").length()));
        System.out.println("i count: " + (length - vowels.replace("i", "").length()));
        System.out.println("o count: " + (length - vowels.replace("o", "").length()));
        System.out.println("u count: " + (length - vowels.replace("u", "").length()));
    }
  }
```

purely simplifing the count vowels part, not discussing if a method is as it should be